# How do I filter items in the Auction House by additional damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

So I'm trying to buy a Source item for my Wizard to get some higher damage. Sources typically come with additional damage and some number of other mods. However, I don't see any way to search, sort, or filter those items by additional damage. The same applies to Witch Doctor Mojos, and Rings.

Is there any way to get the Auction House to show me Wizard Source, Witch Doctor Mojo, or Ring items by damage?

[image: Screenshot of the Search tab in the Diablo 3 auction house; the item display for a Rare Source has "+13-24 Damage" highlighted]

Comment: You can sort by "All Damage" on most items, but not off hands.

Comment: I believe the same is true for rings. I tried yesterday, found no option.

Comment: There is no "all damage" option anymore. See answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A change for this was introduced with patch 1.02 today.

> The "Physical Damage" Preferred Stats option for rings has been renamed to "Bonus Minimum Physical Damage"
>
> The "All Damage" Preferred Stats option for weapons and armor has been removed and replaced with bonuses of specific damage types

You should now be able to search for **Bonus Minimum Physical Damage** to find those +Damage Rings, Amulets, offhands, etc.

Comment: You still don't seem to be able to search for "Bonus Minimum Physical Damage" on offhand items like Mojos.

Comment: A corresponding "Bonus Maximum Physical Damage" seems to be asked too much.

Comment: This is incorrect. Rings and armor cannot be searched like this.

Answer (score 12):

In one of the greatest oversights possibly imagined, there's currently absolutely no way to search for or sort by the damage granted by off-hands, only the other stats you may find on them. I'd suggest posting this on the [bug report forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/5386229/) in the hopes that in a future patch they'll add it in - not having it makes acquiring new offhands a rather irritating affair.

Answer (score 3):

As of the 1.05 patch, it is possible to search off-hand items and jewelry with an attribute of "Average Damage".  This is the middle of the + damage range for the item.  So an item with +10-20 damage would have Average Damage of 15.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do that. "All damage" as stated about is not weapon damage. It may be reduction or something, but definitely not damage.