# How do I find Rings with +Damage in the auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I filter items in the Auction House by additional damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69033/how-do-i-filter-items-in-the-auction-house-by-additional-damage)

I would like to buy a ring with +Damage from the auction house (e.g. Ring of Wounding).
In theory, I should be able to select "Damage" from the "Preferred Stats" Dropdowns and add a minimum value. The only thing that is offered there is "All Damage", which results in no items found. Searching for other stats did show that there are rare rings with +Damage available. 
So, is there a way to directly search for the +Damage stat on a ring?

Answer (score 3):

The proper criteria is "all damage"

The fact that nothing showed up means nothing is being auctioned for your criteria (and level). Or, much more likely the AH is Having trouble.

Comment: Ok, one more try revealed to me that your suggestion only results in rings with +minimum damage or +maximum damage, not e.g. + 3-6 damage. In that sense you are right, there were no rings with these properties available for the char I was looking from

Answer (score 1):

As of the current version of Diablo III and it's Auction House, there is **no way** to effectively search for these items. While the 'All Damage' property from the drop down *should* be what you're looking for, it will not return any results at this time.

Comment: This is not correct. I'll post results when I get home