# How can I search for +mindmg-maxdmg attribute in the AH?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I filter items in the Auction House by additional damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69033/how-do-i-filter-items-in-the-auction-house-by-additional-damage)

Example: +4-8 damage ring

I can't see a way to search for the +4-8 damage part.
The "extra minimum damage" filter won't show this attribute.

Is there a way to find such items?

Comment: ^ your answer is up there ^

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I looked it up first, obviously missed this one.